# Does "other" refer to that particular instance or all cards of the same name?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example [Chief of the Edge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386504) has the ability:

> Other Warrior creatures you control get +1/+0.

So I understand that it would definitely affect [Avalanche Tusker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386483). But if I play another Chief of the Edge, do they mutually affect each other, giving each other +1/+0 (and my Tusker +2/+0)?

Other examples where "other" is used in this way include [Adaptive Automaton](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220147) and [Armament Master](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=190420).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Other creatures you control" means "Creatures you control which are not this object." Chief of the Edge further restricts things by only affecting Warriors.

If the ability did not affect creatures with the same name, it would read something like "Creatures you control not named "Chief of the Edge"..."

Comment: And in general, any time a card wants to refer to all cards of a given name, it will specifically use the word "named".

Answer (score 1):

You are right, they give each other +1/+0 as it says on the card. But not the the  [Armament Master](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=190420). because this is of type Soldier, not warrior.

Comment: I meant the other two as examples of where "other" is used, not examples of where the +1/+0 might apply, sorry for the confusion. I'll update my question.